# First time using ESP 32 and Micro Python

Tags: esp32, micropython

I am trying to program ESP-Wroom-32 (for a University project). I watched tutorials on YouTube and read on websites on how do that. I installed the USB to UART driver from [here](https://www.silabs.com/developers/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers?tab=downloads) and the Micro Python from [here](https://micropython.org/download/#esp32). After Installing the driver i connected the board to my PC and at Ports USB to UART.... COM3 appeared. Later I installed esp tool with:

```
pip install esptool
```

then tried to erase the flash with:

```
python -m esptool --port COM3 erase_flash
```

After running the erase_flash command I got "A fatal error occurred: Could not open COM3, the port doesn't exist"

To make sure that I am not wrong with the COM3 part I unplugged and plugged to see which port appears and disappears. It was COM3. But still the same fatal error. After searching in the internet found anything helpful most of the "Could not open COM3" errors were for an IDE. I Used command prompt for installing esptool and erasing the flash. Found something on the Internet saying that It could be a Windows problem not a faulty driver or ESP32 error.
Has anyone experienced the same problem? What could be the problem? How can I fix this? Thanks in advance :) .

I am using Windows 10 Education.

**Note:**

I have to use USB 3.0 because the Device Manager doesn't recognize the USB to UART on USB 2.0 . Not always I can see the USB to UART in Device Manager when plugged in USB 3.0 (it's like 50/50 chance).
[Ports In Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaZpo.png)

[Device manager not recognizing the Chip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vySyz.png)

**EDIT** The ESP32 board was faulty. It wasn't the cable or the drivers.

Comment: One suggestion is to try a different USB cable. Sounds silly, but I once had a similar random disconnect problem and it turned out to be a damaged cable. Also, you may want to look at Thonny https://thonny.org to download their Python IDE. It does a nice job of auto-detecting the device, flashing firmware, etc. Easier than the command-line tools in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using a different USB cable same problem. I also tried Thonny. Thonny detected the COM3 but when i started flashing the same fatal error appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my drivers/windows (on my PC). I guess there are some restrictions with the newer updates for Windows 10. My laptop has Windows 10 (but the older version + the Windows license has ended) and it works. Device manager recognizes the UART and everything.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linux seems to be the way forward if Windows drivers have mysteriously changed or Windows security features shut down access to loading binary images.

Somehow, ArduinoIDE seems to successfully load compiled C or C++. but Python and MicroPython loading isn't able to do the same

Comment: The problem was with the micro controller. The board itself was faulty therefore not working with Python. There was a post here for checking if the board is working or not but I cannot find it. It was something like running a cmd command that returns info about the board and if the board returns 00000000 or FFFFFFFF (which was my case) It means that the board has a faulty chip.
So i switched to ESP8266 and now my sensor Is working.